# how to capture array in ajax page when sent through JSON object

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

i am sending an array from one page to another through ajax.i used JSON object for this purpose.I am able to send but i am not able to capture in the ajax page.Please help me how to capture the array values.
javascript:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataString);
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxpage.php",
        data: {data : jsonString}, 
        cache: false,

        success: function(response){
            alert("ok");
           $('#test').html(response);
        }
    });
```

PHP page:

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

  // here i would like use foreach:

  foreach($data as $d){
     echo $d;
  }
```

please help me in this regard.
I am stuck up here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to decode the JSON into an associative array, you should specify that in `json_decode`:

Replace

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
```

With

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']), true);
```

See [`json_decode` reference](https://www.php.net/json_decode) for more information

---

Also, is `dataString` possibly already a JSON string?

Comment: dataString = document.getElementById('theNumbers').value ; // array
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataString);This is the code i have written

Comment: it is not working for me Kim Gysen.Can you please tell me where i am  going wrong

Comment: Actually stringifying a stringified string seems to work as well, just tested it. What do you get if you just console.log teh result of print_r(json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']), true))?

Comment: I am not getting anything when i executed the above statement. i,e Empty

Comment: Then what do you get when: console.log(jsonString); It's prolly a good idea to use the error clause in the ajax call: error: function (xhr,status,error) {}); Possibly there could be something wrong with the format of the stringified object that makes the json_decode() function fail.

Comment: hi Kim Gysen I have done this and I am able to clear the issue it is working fine for me now.Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, I have tried and it works
in your php:

```
<?php
$data = ($_POST['data']);

foreach($data as $d){
    echo stripslashes($d);
}
?>
```

in your jsvascript/jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(){
    var dataString = {
        'id':'1',
        'name':'peter parker',
        'age':'unknown',
        'role':'spiderman'
    }
    $.ajax({
         url: "<?php echo $this->webroot;?>test_1.php",
         data: {'data':dataString}, 
         type: "POST",
         cache: false,
         success: function(response){
         alert("ok");
         $('#test').html(response);
        }
     });
   })
})
</script>
```

in your html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Click Me</a>
<div id="test"></div>
```